# How to trigger code before and after queues in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I am trying to work on a multi tenant multi database application which basically means that every tenant has its own database, own users, resources etc.

Naturally when a request comes in, Laravel needs to know which DB connection to use so I wrote a middleware which basically parses the JWT in the requests and looks for the tenant id or username then simply connects to the tenant's database.

This works well for requests but now I am stuck with queues. I am trying to run queues for tenants like for sending emails, but before even firing the handle method, laravel tries to fetch the user from the default Db and fails or fetches the wrong user of course.

Is there a way to call code before a queue handle method fires off? Is there a before and after method for laravel queues that I don't know about?

Comment: I looking for the same thing, did you get any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a before or after event.

Why don't you pass that information as part of the package to the handle method so when the job is processed it has the data it needs.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#job-class-structure

In the `__construct` method set the tenant id or whatever else you need access to in the handle method and this data will be serialised when sent to the queue. Then when the queue processes the job you will have access to the tenant id just like you would the user model which is in that example.